# Search methods and string matching in python

Tags: python, full-text-search, string-matching, text-mining

I have a task to search for a group of specific terms(around 138000 terms) in a table made of 4 columns and 187000 rows. The column headers are `id`, `title`, `scientific_title` and `synonyms`, where each column might contain more than one term inside it.

I should end up with a csv table with the id where a term has been found and the term itself. What could be the best and the fastest way to do so?

In my script, I tried creating phrases by iterating over the different words in a term in order and comparing each word with each row of each column of the table.

It looks something like this:

```
title_prepared = string_preparation(title)
sentence_array = title_prepared.split(" ")
length = len(sentence_array)

for i in range(length):

    for place_length in range(len(sentence_array)):

        last_element = place_length + 1
        phrase = ' '.join(sentence_array[0:last_element])

        if phrase in literalhash:
            final_dict.setdefault(id,[])
            if not phrase in final_dict[id]:
                final_dict[trial_id].append(phrase)
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some info on why your existing code isn't satisfactory? Too slow, missing data, formatting it poorly?

Comment: By "best" way of doing this do you "most elegant," or something else?  As the other commenter asked, what's wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: The problem is that we are missing some terms that we are sure should be present in ou rfinal table.

Comment: Yeah, the 'Most Elegant' way would be a nice description of what i need!

Comment: Which format does the input table have? `csv`?

Comment: You should add some sample input to your question.

Comment: So your code doesn't work properly, and you also want an elegant solution? Why not get the code working first? At a quick glance I can see a couple of problems - your for loops are actually iterating over the same range and the i variable doesn't appear to be used. Your code doesn't show how literalhash is initialised so there might be something wrong there. Have you tried using a smaller dataset and adding some print statements to debug? Have you tried doing a written description of the algorithm and running through it on paper with some data?

Comment: My colleague gave more details abou the script used in the answer below.

Comment: it looks like the code on the website you pointed at assumes all text is lowercase - at least it is case sensitive - have you tried looking for heart disease (rather than Heart Disease)?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problem: we are running small scientific project where we need to extract all text parts with particular keywords. We have used coded dictionary and python script posted on http://www.julesberman.info/coded.htm ! But it seems that something does not working properly.

For exemple the script do not recognize a keyword "Heart Disease" in string "A Multicenter Randomized Trial Evaluating the Efficacy of Sarpogrelate on Ischemic Heart Disease After Drug-eluting Stent Implantation in Patients With Diabetes Mellitus or Renal Impairment".

Thanks for understanding! we are a biologist and medical doctor, with little bit knowlege of python!

If you need some more code i would post it online.

Comment: Don't add information about the question as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, i am in hospital behind some firewals and filters... website is not shown propperly... i will be more careful nex time

Answer (score 0):

The code on the website you link to is case-sensitive - it will only work when the terms in tumorabs.txt and neocl.xml are the exact same case. If you can't change your data then change:

After:

```
for line in text:
```

add:

```
    line = line.lower()
```

(this is indented four spaces)

And change:

```
  phrase = ' '.join(sentence_array[0:last_element])
```

to:

```
  phrase = ' '.join(sentence_array[0:last_element]).lower()
```

AFAICT this works with the unmodified code from the website when I change the case of some of the data in tumorabs.txt and neocl.xml.